# Bash standard output display and redirection at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

In terminal, sometimes I would like to display the standard output and also save it as a backup. but if I use redirection ( `>` `&>` etc), it does not display the output in the terminal anymore.

I think I can do for example `ls > localbackup.txt | cat localbackup.txt`. But it just doesn't feel right. Is there any shortcut to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tee` is the command you are looking for:

```
ls | tee localbackup.txt
```

Comment: @YolandYan accepting a correct answer is also a way to thank someone for their help.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `tee` to duplicate the output (and it's worth mentioning that `tee` is able to append to the file instead of overwriting it, by using `tee -a`, so that you can run several commands in sequence and retain all of the output), you can also use `tail -f` to "follow" the output file from a parallel process (e.g. a separate terminal):

```
command1 >localbackup.txt    # create output file
command2 >>localbackup.txt   # append to output
```

and from a separate terminal, at the same time:

```
tail -f localbackup.txt    # this will keep outputting as text is appended to the file
```